# How to check in javascript if date is a monday

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have this dateTime - picker and now I will only allow (all) mondays:

```
<input type="text"
    class="form-control scheduleFrom"
    name="scheduleFrom"                                
    ng-model="vm.scheduleIntervalContainerWeeksFrom"
    datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"
    is-open="vm.openedDatePickerFrom"
    close-text="schlie&szlig;en"
    current-text="heute"
    clear-text="l&ouml;schen"
    date-disabled="vm.disabledFrom(date, mode)">
```

Currently this is my disable- function:

```
vm.disabledFrom = function(date, mode) { 
    return mode === 'day' && date < vm.scheduleIntervalContainerWeeksFrom;
};
```

Thanks for any hints

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how to check in javascript if date it a monday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check that your date is a Monday:

```
date.getDay() === 1
```

See [Date.prototype.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following link  ,it may help--
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_date_weekday

Comment: Posting a link isn't an answer. Please don't reference w3schools, it has many errors and misleading information. The language specification ([*ECMA-262]*(http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getday)) and [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) are much better references.